# Shell command to find the newest created files recursively from a root directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, shell

Is there a shell command to find the newest created files recursively from a root directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find /mydir -type f -exec stat -c '%y %N' {} \; | sort -n
```

Comment: You may want to tweak "%y". Refer to "man stat".

Comment: In general, you should avoid using -exec for security reasons. GNU find offers -execdir as an alternative.

Answer (score 6):

This method uses only `find` (and `sort`):

```
find /somedir -type f -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

You can constrain it to the most recent 3 days, for example, like this:

```
find . -type f -mtime -3 -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

Or the last 42.5 hours:

```
find . -type f -mmin -2550 -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

which is the same as:

```
find . -type f -mmin -$((42 * 60 + 30)) -printf "%T+ %p\n" | sort
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid forking one process per file checked, if you're on a machine with GNU versions of find and xargs, consider something like this:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c '%Y %N' | sort -n
```

Comment: with no time limit on find, it would match a lot more files.

Answer (score 0):

This handles spaces correctly and executes a command (`ls` in this case) on a per file basis. Change (or delete) `-n1` to execute the command on multiple files simultaneously.

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -z -nr | cut -z -d' ' -f2- |xargs -0 -n1 ls
```